# How to find fields in a unknown table in a database?

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, select, field

Good morning!

I'm with the need to look in my database, one column of a table that does not know the name at first, what happens is the following:

In my application created for each project, a table is created which takes the name of this project, taking the given name and concatenating with the date and time of creation. So the name of this table is stored in another table called projects that have a field that tells the client that belongs to that project. When I do SELECT want to see the names of application projects related to the ID's of customers, browse the database tables behind those those customers and bring me these tables, so that we can finally see the desired fields.

Do not know if I could be clear, if they need more details just talk!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to find the exact names of the tables that were named like your project plus they have some additional characters in their names (that look like dates and times).

Well, you can list all the tables that start with the name of your project, using a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE 'yourprojectname%'
```

`sys.tables` is a system view where all your tables are listed.

`'yourprojectname%'` is a mask used for filtering through the list of tables. The `%` character is neccessary. It means *'any character or characters, any number of them (or none of them)'*. (Without `%` the output would show you only one table whose name is *exactly* like your project's name. If such a table exists, that is.)